# Removing entry from DYNAMIC section of elf file

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, static-linking, elf

I have 3rd party library **A**, that requires some library **B**.
**A** is linked to binrary, which is linked with static version **B**. 
Therefore there's no need in dynamic version of **B** any more.

**A** is not under my control and I cannot recompile it. Thus I want to remove `NEEDED libA` entry from **DYNAMIC** section of **A**.

Is there a way to do it with objcopy or other tool?

Comment: Odds are 90% or higher that removing the NEEDED entry will just produce an unresolvable symbol error (if you're lucky) or a malfunctioning program (if you're not so lucky, due to duplication of data that must be unique).  You should instead relink the binary against a dynamic version of library B.

Comment: @Zack I link my binary against static version of B, so there should not be unresolved symbols. Do you still think I'll have a problem?

Comment: Yes.  Your binary contains only the subset of B that the binary itself uses.  This is very likely not to be adequate for A as well.  Why is it a problem to link against a dynamic version of B?

Comment: @Zack I don't want to install B on production server, since there's other version of B. This 2 versions of B may conflict.

Comment: @Zack But A is part of binary, so all its undefined symbols should be resolved at link time of binary with A and B. Am I correct?

Comment: That is true if A is a *static* library, but your question implies that it is a dynamic library (static libraries do not have a `DYNAMIC` table).  The linker will *not* pull in material from B in order to resolve undefined references in a dynamic library A; it will assume that A's `NEEDED`s satisfy all of A's references.

Comment: You can install two versions of B on your production server as long as their `soname`s are different.  If their `soname`s are not different, then the newer B is *supposed* to be backward compatible with the older one.  If you tell me the actual identities of A and B, I may be able to tell you whether the developers of B are likely to have gotten this right.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do it with objcopy or other tool?

I don't know of any existing tool that can do this, although [elfsh](http://www.eresi-project.org/wiki/TheELFsh) might be able to.

It is quite trivial to write a C program to do what you want: the `.dynamic` section of `libA.so` is a table of fixed-size records (of type `ElfW(Dyn)`), terminated by an entry with `.d_type == DT_NULL`. To get rid of a particular `DT_NEEDED` entry, simply "slide" all following entries up (overwriting `entry[n]` with `entry[n+1]`, etc.). This will leave your `.dynamic` with two `DT_NULL` entries at the end, but nothing should ever care.

One complication is that if `libB.so` contains *versioned* symbols that `libA.so` references, then there will be additional references to `libB.so` in `DT_VERNEED` table, and these are more difficult to get rid of. If you don't get rid of `VERNEED` references, the dynamic linker will fail assertions.